# Getting a not valid month and need to insert records in incremental manner

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE deligate_details_main (
    e_id NUMBER(10),completed_date timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT pk_deligate_details_main PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);

INSERT INTO deligate_details_main VALUES(1,current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO deligate_details_main VALUES(2,current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO deligate_details_main VALUES(3,current_timestamp);

CREATE SEQUENCE deligate_details_trans_sq;

CREATE TABLE deligate_details_trans (
    d_id  NUMBER(10),
    e_id  NUMBER(10),
    completed_date_trans date,
    CONSTRAINT pk_deligate_details_trans PRIMARY KEY ( d_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_e_id FOREIGN KEY ( e_id )
        REFERENCES deligate_details_main ( e_id )
);

insert into deligate_details_trans(d_id,e_id,completed_date_trans)
select deligate_details_trans_sq.nextval,
e_id,
to_date(completed_date,'DD-MON-YY') from deligate_details_main;
```

The problem which I am facing:

1. I need to convert timestamp to date and then insert it into the deligate_details_trans for the completed_date column of the deligate_details_main table. When I am converting it is giving ORA-01843: not a valid month error.
2. Currently, deligate_details_main has 3 rows that are going to be inserted into the deligate_details_trans table but if any rows got inserted into the deligate_details_main table say e_id 4 got inserted after doing insertion into the deligate_details_trans table. Then when I will run the INSERT query then it should append e_id 4 into the deligate_details_trans table

Expected Output if there are 3 records into the deligate_details_main table:

```
+------+------+----------------------+
| D_ID | E_ID | completed_date_trans |
+------+------+----------------------+
|    1 |    1 | 13-Dec-21            |
|    2 |    2 | 13-Dec-21            |
|    3 |    3 | 13-Dec-21            |
+------+------+----------------------+
```

When one more e_id gets added into the deligate_details_main table

```
INSERT INTO deligate_details_main VALUES(4,current_timestamp);
```

Then the output should be:

```
+------+------+----------------------+
| D_ID | E_ID | completed_date_trans |
+------+------+----------------------+
|    1 |    1 | 13-Dec-21            |
|    2 |    2 | 13-Dec-21            |
|    3 |    3 | 13-Dec-21            |
|    4 |    4 | 13-Dec-21            |
+------+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: `TO_DATE`works on a string. So in order to apply it here: `to_date(completed_date,'DD-MON-YY')`, Oracle must convert `completed_date` to a string first. Implicitly this is `to_date(to_char(completed_date),'DD-MON-YY')`. This converts the tmestamp to a string first, but as the format is ommitted, you get it according to session settings, e.g. in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi`. You then tell the DBMS that this string has the format 'DD-MON-YY' and you want it converted to a date, which must fail obviously.

Comment: On a sidenote: `completed_date` is probably a bad name for a column that doesn't only contain a date, but also a time. `completed_datetime` would be more appropriate and may prevent you from making mistakes in your queries. Moreover, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (the session's time) is rarely used in Oracle. We would typically rather use `SYSTIMESTAMP`, which is the database system's time.

Comment: As to your second part: I don't see the benefit of inserting a dummy row in the details table automatically. All the information is in the main table, so why insert an empty detail row at all? Insert details only when you have some detail information to store, I'd say.

Comment: Also asked at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4492440/getting-a-not-valid-month-and-need-to-insert-records-in-incremental-manner#latest

Comment: @EdStevens Yes. Are these two platforms are same? I thought I may get some other logic as well as I am in the learning phase. Also, should I avoid asking on oracle community If both are same?

Comment: @Vicky - they are not the same, but there is a large overlap of participants.  Also, working two different sites at once can lead to a lot of confusion if the responders on one site follow a different path of inquiry than those on another.  Even more so if you start to inject input from one site on the other.  When I have a problem I start with one particular site, and would only start a thread on another in the rare instance the first didn't yield a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `TRUNC` on `completed_date`, I'd say.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO deligate_details_trans (d_id, e_id, completed_date_trans)
  2     SELECT deligate_details_trans_sq.NEXTVAL, e_id, TRUNC (completed_date)
  3       FROM deligate_details_main;

3 rows created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM deligate_details_trans;

      D_ID       E_ID COMPLETED_
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1 13.12.2021
         5          2 13.12.2021
         6          3 13.12.2021

SQL>
```

---

To make inserts into `deligate_details_trans` *automatic*, you'll need a database **trigger**:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ai_ddm
  2     AFTER INSERT
  3     ON deligate_details_main
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     INSERT INTO deligate_details_trans (d_id, e_id, completed_date_trans)
  7             VALUES (deligate_details_trans_sq.NEXTVAL,
  8                     :new.e_id,
  9                     TRUNC (:new.completed_date));
 10  END trg_ai_ddm;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO deligate_details_main VALUES(4,current_timestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM deligate_details_trans;

      D_ID       E_ID COMPLETED_
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1 13.12.2021
         5          2 13.12.2021
         6          3 13.12.2021
         7          4 13.12.2021         --> here it is!

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround but how will add e_id 4 in the same go. If any new id gets inserted into the main table then after running insert query of trans table then that record should be added into the trans table

Comment: You'll need a trigger; have a look at edited answer (and - sorry for not posting it earlier; missed that part of the question).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should work for me. Just one more query while inserting into the table can we join multiple tables to get the e_id? Here I have pasted the sample data but in actual I need e_id by joining 3 tables. So, can I join those tables and theninsert using triggers?

Comment: Trigger doesn't care about that; you can select from any number of tables you want. Trigger will fire once you run the INSERT INTO DELIGATE_DETAILS_MAIN table and "fetch" the E_ID value you inserted (and then "transfer" it into DELIGATE_DETAILS_TRANS).

Comment: Any example would be appreciated :) Or can I request another question?

Comment: I don't have any examples. You said that `INSERT INTO deligate_details_trans` uses a SELECT statement that JOINS 3 tables - you know which ones, I don't.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will try with the joins and if stuck anywhere will sk in the community